# View sendTransaction implementation

Tags: metamask, json-rpc, rpc

I'd like to see code that implements [`getAccounts`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#getaccounts) and `sendTransaction` in a provider.

I tried digging into the Metamask source code and found the line where Metamask supplies [the Web3 provider](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/develop/app/scripts/inpage.js#L155), but I couldn't figure out where this provider implements `sendTransaction` or `getAccounts`.

How/where are these methods implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to check the [Guide to Porting MetaMask to a New Environment](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/v7.1.1/docs/porting_to_new_environment.md). Even if you are not porting MetaMask it is useful because it explains the project organization.

If you search for `getAccounts` in MetaMask you will find it in [createMetamaskMiddleware.js](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/v7.1.1/app/scripts/controllers/network/createMetamaskMiddleware.js). It passes it among other functions to `createWalletSubprovider`

```
createWalletSubprovider({
  getAccounts,
  processTransaction,
  processEthSignMessage,
  processTypedMessage,
  processTypedMessageV3,
  processTypedMessageV4,
  processPersonalMessage,
}),
```

Which is provided in a separate [repo](https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-json-rpc-middleware/blob/master/wallet.js). This middleware will map JSON-RPC requests to functions in MetaMask extension.

- eth_accounts => getAccounts
- eth_sendTransaction => processTransaction

You can determine the implementations of the functions examing the parameters of `createMetamaskMiddleware` when it is being called.

If you follow through some hops you will find it is done at [MetamaskController.initializeProvider](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/v7.1.1/app/scripts/metamask-controller.js#L306-L340)

For example you have for `getAccounts`:

```
  getAccounts: async ({ origin }) => {
    // Expose no accounts if this origin has not been approved, preventing
    // account-requring RPC methods from completing successfully
    const exposeAccounts = this.providerApprovalController.shouldExposeAccounts(origin)
    if (origin !== 'MetaMask' && !exposeAccounts) { return [] }
    const isUnlocked = this.keyringController.memStore.getState().isUnlocked
    const selectedAddress = this.preferencesController.getSelectedAddress()
    // only show address if account is unlocked
    if (isUnlocked && selectedAddress) {
      return [selectedAddress]
    } else {
      return []
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll carefully study them.